# Javascript: Delete a div that contains (3) in a row <BR>'s in it

Tags: javascript, html

```
<div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
</div>
```

I have an HTML page that has the above div element in it. How can I scan the page an look for a DIV that contains specific items? In this example I know I have three `<br>` in a row and that's it. The DIV element does not have a class or an ID, and I would like to delete it.

Comment: Please post your code so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can target elements in a row by using the sibling selector, `+`. You can make sure the target elements are a direct child of the div by using the `>` selector.

You can find the div that contains the three `br` elements like so:

```
document.querySelector('div > br + br + br').parentNode;
```

To remove this element from the DOM use the `remove` method.

```
const elToDelete = document.querySelector('div > br + br + br')?.parentNode;

elToDelete?.remove();
```

Edit:
Added [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) syntax to the answer to show how to prevent undefined errors from being thrown.

Comment: don't forget to check for it's existence, otherwise you'll get undefined has no attribute delete

Comment: Also check @apple-apple answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/73722873/6519981. Their's will be more robust if you have multiple elements of div's containing br's.

Comment: This will only work with one element. You would have to add document.querySelectorAll and then a loop to get all div tags on the page.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `:has` pseudo-class to select the `div` directly

```js
var elem = document.querySelectorAll("div:has(>br+br+br)");
console.log([...elem])
elem.forEach(x=>x.remove())
```

```html
<div id=a> a
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
</div>

<div id=b> b
  <br/>
  <br/>
</div>

<div id=c> c
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <not-br/>
  <br/>
</div>
```

Comment: :has() pseudo-class currently has poor browser support.  See https://caniuse.com/css-has.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
[].slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName("div")).forEach(function(div){
    var count = 0;
    if(div.children.length === 3)   
        [].slice.call(div.children).forEach(function(br, i){
            if(br.nodeName === "BR")
                count++;
        });
    if(count > 2)
        div.parentElement.removeChild(div);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just hide it with CSS

```css
div:has(>br+br+br) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div>1</div>
<div><br/><br/><br/></div>
<div>3</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Best solution that will work cross-browser is to tackle this programmatically.  Note that :has() pseudo class doesn't work on Firefox, IE or Opera (see https://caniuse.com/css-has).

Here's a concise functional Javascript approach:

```
[].filter.call(document.querySelectorAll('div'), el => el.querySelectorAll('br').length === 3)
```